# Uniqueness of Pseudo inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $X\succeq0$, we can write the SVD decomposition as:
\begin{align}
X&= U \begin{bmatrix}\Omega&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}U^T,
\end{align}
where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Omega\succ0$.

My question is whether
\begin{align}
Y&= U \begin{bmatrix}\Omega^{-1} &0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}U^T,
\end{align}
is the unique Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $X$.

Comment: Every matrix has a unique pseudo inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to the [Moore-Penrose peudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) and that $\Omega \succ 0$ means that $\Omega$ is positive definite, which implies that $\Omega$ is symmetric.

Yes, your formula for the psuedoinverse is correct, and (as is generally the case) the MP pseudoinverse is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If a matrix $M$ is a Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$, then $$AMA=A,~~~ MAM=M,~~~(AM)^{'}=AM,~~~(MA)^{'}=MA.$$
Omitting the existence, we just prove the uniqueness. Suppose there are two candidates MP inverses $M_1,M_2$ of $A$. Then
$$M_1 = M_1 A M_1 = M_1 (AM_1)^{'}=M_1 M_1^{'}A^{'} = M_1 M_1^{'} A^{'} M_2 A^{'}$$
$$= M_1 M_1^{'} A^{'} A M_2=M_1A M_1 A M_2 = M_1 A M_2=M_1 A M_2 A M_2 = M_1 A A^{'} M_2^{'} M_2$$
$$= A^{'} M_1^{'} A^{'} M_2^{'} M_2 = A^{'} M_2^{'} M_2 = M_2AM_2=M_2.$$